# Reachability for Today Widget

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, reachability, ios8-today-widget

I got a Notification Center Widget that contains some UISwitches that work only if connected to a Wi-Fi network.

I tried to do this with [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) (that works in the normal app code), like this

```
#import "Reachability.h"
```

---

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];

NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if(status == NotReachable) {        

    switch.enabled = NO;

} else if (status == ReachableViaWiFi) {



} else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN) {

    switch.enabled = NO;

}
```

But I got these errors

[image]

Comment: Have you try to import the SystemConfiguration framework? And check whether your extension has added this code.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work

Comment: can you check whether Reachability.m file is added in "Compile Sources" within Build Phase tab in your app target?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your not add `Reachability.m` as **Target Membership** of your widget

[image: Target Membership]